# Send E-Mail in C++

Tags: c++, email

Im trying to send an email in C++. I found the class CSmtp which looks like a fine one.So I tried out the example project but it gives the ErrorCode :

> Error: Undefined error id.

Now I tried to find out where the problem is because the errorcode is too general.I Debuged the project find this Errorcode

> ```
>   ErrorCode   WSA_SELECT (109)    ECSmtp::CSmtpError
> ```

I googled after it but found no answer.Someone can help ?

Link for class : [CSmtp with SSL/TLS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/smtp_ssl.aspx?fid=1581585&df=90&mpp=10&noise=3&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=4100122&fr=31)

Code:

```
    #include "CSmtp.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool bError = false;

    try
    {
        CSmtp mail;

#define test_gmail_tls

#if defined(test_gmail_tls)
        mail.SetSMTPServer("smtp.gmail.com",587);
        mail.SetSecurityType(USE_TLS);
#elif defined(test_gmail_ssl)
        mail.SetSMTPServer("smtp.gmail.com",465);
        mail.SetSecurityType(USE_SSL);
#elif defined(test_hotmail_TLS)
        mail.SetSMTPServer("smtp.live.com",25);
        mail.SetSecurityType(USE_TLS);
#elif defined(test_aol_tls)
        mail.SetSMTPServer("smtp.aol.com",587);
        mail.SetSecurityType(USE_TLS);
#elif defined(test_yahoo_ssl)
        mail.SetSMTPServer("plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com",465);
        mail.SetSecurityType(USE_SSL);
#endif

        mail.SetLogin("* My Email Adress *");
        mail.SetPassword("*Password*");
        mail.SetSenderName("User");
        mail.SetSenderMail("* My Email Adress *");
        mail.SetReplyTo("* Email Adress of my friend *");
        mail.SetSubject("The message");
        mail.SetXPriority(XPRIORITY_NORMAL);
        mail.SetXMailer("The Bat! (v3.02) Professional");
        mail.AddMsgLine("Hello,");
        mail.AddMsgLine("");
        mail.AddMsgLine("...");
        mail.AddMsgLine("How are you today?");
        mail.AddMsgLine("");
        mail.AddMsgLine("Regards");
        mail.ModMsgLine(5,"regards");
        mail.DelMsgLine(2);
        mail.AddMsgLine("User");

        //mail.AddAttachment("../test1.jpg");
        //mail.AddAttachment("c:\\test2.exe");
        //mail.AddAttachment("c:\\test3.txt");
        mail.Send();
    }
    catch(ECSmtp e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.GetErrorText().c_str() << ".\n";
        bError = true;
    }
    if(!bError)
        std::cout << "Mail was send successfully.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: edited. Ofc the Email & Pass is not the true one

Comment: It is the real code ? I only hided my password and email.

Comment: What is missing from this question is details which library you are using. `CSmtp` doesn't tell us a lot. "C" is a common prefix for class types, and SMTP is a mail protocol, so this just tells us you're working with a class that handles mail. But which class from which library?

Comment: Im a newbie so I dont understand what you mean.The class uses the openSSL library if you mean this.I just get it from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/smtp_ssl.aspx?fid=1581585&df=90&mpp=10&noise=3&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=4100122&fr=31)

Comment: It looks like you are coding a spam bot. I'm not sure it is legal; and I am not sure you'll get help here, and details are system & ISP specific.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Eh, why do you think he is coding a "spam bot"? There are very many legitimate reasons to send email from a C++ program. SO rules: _assume good faith_.

Comment: Of course they are good reasons to send email from a C++ program (and I did that already), but then the programmer knows enough about SMTP to avoid going directly thru `smtp.gmail.com` but will go thru his trusted SMTP host.

Comment: How on and on which machines & networks your C++ program sending email will run?

Comment: It is just a school project nothing else. So were using Windows 7 with VS 2012.I just have to send a mail to my classmate through GMail (in C++ of course). It also can be another protocol

Comment: Then, use the SMTP server of your school. So code your C++ program to use SMTP with your school's SMTP server. You need to read more about SMTP.

Comment: @Kleeman I was able to compile the sample code provided in CodeProject after the Visual Studio Wizard (VS2010 here) did upate the solution.The error it is giving you is at compile/link time or at run time in the output console?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch please do not be rude, I also have the need to programmatically send emails (I'm developing a Surveilance System with automatic email in case of intrusion) and the customer wants to use his google account.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go with powershell script for sending email and then call that script from your c++ program. Use smtp.gmail.com as server & 465 port. :)
This can help..
https://github.com/udit043/Send-email-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++11 does not have such facilities (but your particular OS might provide additional SMTP client libraries). Maybe you want a library like [vmime](http://www.vmime.org) or a framework like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)

Notice that the very ability of email is operating system specific.
Also, most [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) servers are configured to reject [open mail relaying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay) (otherwise, they would be used by spam bots, and emails going thru them would be rejected since blacklisted).

You could for example configure some SMTP service on your local machine or server, and programmatically send email thru  `localhost` (then the SMTP server would spool and relay the email, etc.) - or to some specific and well-defined "[smarthost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host)" if your system and network has one; you probably don't want to wire-in some SMTP relay host names in your program, and you do want the email to be spooled (not lost!) if the recipient SMTP server is down or unreachable; in other words, you need some SMTP server.

<sup>You certainly don't want to code your SMTP server from scratch!</sup>

Hence, your program should only send SMTP to some trusted host, which is correctly configured to avoid spamming (then you might need to set some `From` or `Reply-To` SMTP header to something appropriate for your SMTP host). Be sure that major Internet companies like Google, Yahoo, AOL etc... are configuring carefully their SMTP service to disallow open relay spamming. Often, they accept SMTP relay connections only from their business clients (and they would cut a client doing automated spamming). So you should send SMTP to your ISP's SMTP server (or to some local or near SMTP server).

Notice that spamming is usually forbidden by law or by your ISP terms of service.

You could also run some command (e.g. using `popen`) to send mail ...

Comment: Ehmm... For what is this class then ? It's a normal c++ class isn't it ? There are many comments that it works under Windows and VS

Comment: It is just non standard.

Comment: Are there no ways to send E-Mail in C++ through these companies like Google etc. ? Thanks for your explaination

Comment: You need to go thru your ISP SMTP service. It is not a matter of programming, it is  a sysadmin matter, and your ISP probably forbids spamming

Comment: Quit accusing everyone of "spamming" please